# Reuse a Fiber in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nonblocking, eventmachine, fiber

I use `EventMachine.open_keyboard` in my irc client app that uses rbcurse (ncurses gem), as follows:

```
Fiber.new do
    EM.open_keyboard(NbKeyboard) do |kb|
        $input = Readline.readline("")
        $buffer << $input
    end
end.resume
```

This code has to be in a Fiber and catch input in a nonblocking way. After I try to type a second line, ruby throws a "dead fiber" exception. I tried adding loops, but that blocks as well, and changing the fiber into a thread doesn't work with the keyboard module. Other ways I tried block all my threads, one of which is responsible for keeping the buffer updated/refreshed. How can I change the code to keep the Fiber open/alive after typing the first line? To view the keyboard module (didn't write it myself), go [here](http://simulacre.org/unblocking-readline-in-eventmachine/).

Edit:
Thanks to the answer of **Sawa** I figured it out:

```
Fiber.new do
    EM.open_keyboard(NbKeyboard) do |kb|
        loop do
            $input = Readline.readline("")
            $buffer << $input
            Fiber.yield
        end
    end
 end.resume
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
loop{Fiber.yield}
```

at the end of the fiber body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it somewhat helped, the application doesn't crash and I can type as many lines as I want, but they are not added to the buffer. How to fix this?